# Vue/vuetify v-switch: what is input-value?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Can someone explain to me exactly what the `input-value` attribute does on the v-switch component?

I think it has something to due with using the component with vuex, when you cannot use v-model directly.

It seems to be working for me, but I don't understand it exactly.

You can see the attribute here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#api

Where it is described as: "The v-model bound value".

(I originally found the attribute in an example somehere.)

Comment: check [Vuetify Github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/mixins/selectable.js#L45)

Comment: @Sphinx That was a good idea.  I can see now that input-value abstracts the component state to a watch value.  But why?  Why is input-value working and `value` isn't?

Comment: what do you mean "Why is input-value working and value isn't?"?

Comment: @Sphinx Why when I bind to `:value` does the component not reflect the value of the binding, but when I bind to `:input-value` it does work?  That is not the case for other components except `<v-switch>`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Vuetify, but from the [source codes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/mixins/selectable.js#L139), `input-value` only affect the initial value. then if attr=`value` of checkbox !== `inputValue`, it will return null instead, like [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLwBMp?editors=1011)

Comment: sorry, it seems enclosed wrong codepen, please removed `value="xx"` instead for the codepen of previous comment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`input-value` behaves like a default `value` attribute that you would expect in other components.
Normally `v-model` is syntax sugar for `:value="value" :input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`, but we can change it.

from [selectable.js](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/215055423b9da1ecbe530b5464b4f770c9a2375b/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/selectable.js):

```
model: {
  prop: 'inputValue',
  event: 'change'
},
```

So the above lines (see [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)) make your `v-model` bind to `input-value` instead of `value` likely because some components i.e. checkbox (which v-switch uses) have `value` attribute reserved for something else.

So `value` attribute is then used to set the value which will be represented when the component is checked.
And in `v-switch` case `v-model` is syntax sugar for something like `:input-value="value" @change="value = $event"`

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZWdjO)