# How to make <v-switch> have default value of "false"

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

Currently I want to make a testimony page using switch to make the testimony appear or active but I have a problem to set the `<v-switch>` to have a default value `false`, Whenever I try to fetch it, It always return a default value `true` even though I already set it to `false`,

I already try to read this but it still can't solve my problem:

[My Vuetify Switch not change his value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011826/my-vuetify-switch-not-change-his-value)

[Vue/vuetify v-switch: what is input-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485069/vue-vuetify-v-switch-what-is-input-value)

This is my siwtch code:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <td>{{ props.item.uuid }}</td>
  <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ props.item.phone }}/5.0</td>
  <td>{{ props.item.jobTitle }}</td>
  <td>
    <div slot="widget-content">
      <div class="basic">
        <v-switch :label="props.item.status ? 'Active': 'Non-Active'" v-model="props.item.status" color="success" @change="getStatus(props.item.status)"></v-switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</template>
```

This is my method:

```
getStatus(status){
  this.status = status;
  console.log("Test Data Status : ", this.status)
}
```

and this is my sample data :

```
const Items =  [
  {
    'uuid': '65a6eb21-67b5-45c3-9af7-faca2d9b60d4',
    'name': 'Dessie',
    'email': 'Dessie7937@gmail.com',
    'username': 'Dessie79',
    'jobTitle': 'Web Developer',
    'phone': '1-360-812-9380 x511',
    'avatar': '/static/avatar/a2.jpg',
    'status': 'false',
    'address': {
      'street': '655 Archibald Groves',
      'suite': 'Apt. 818',
      'city': 'Carlosshire',
      'state': 'Arkansas',
      'country': 'Somalia',
      'zipcode': '10406',
      'geo': {
        'lat': '-44.6063',
        'lng': '-169.7706'
      }
    },
  },
  {
    'uuid': '28d9f265-74d7-4f85-83d4-6a21fca57dcf',
    'name': 'Jakayla',
    'jobTitle': 'Web Designer',
    'email': 'Jakayla_Crooks867@yahoo.com',
    'username': 'Jakayla_Crooks86',
    'phone': '610.499.1240',
    'avatar': '/static/avatar/a3.jpg',
    'status': 'false',
    'address': {
      'street': '281 Tillman Forge',
      'suite': 'Apt. 381',
      'city': 'New Sandrinemouth',
      'state': 'North Dakota',
      'country': 'Reunion',
      'zipcode': '19540-8186',
      'geo': {
        'lat': '-12.3375',
        'lng': '-117.9067'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    'uuid': '14ddae1e-986d-42f4-8d17-46a02d469b2b',
    'name': 'Hobart',
    'jobTitle': 'Sales',
    'email': 'Hobart_Mueller.Thiel@hotmail.com',
    'username': 'Hobart_Mueller',
    'phone': '1-590-385-3349',
    'avatar': 'static/avatar/a1.jpg',
    'status': 'false',
    'address': {
      'street': '706 Padberg Knoll',
      'suite': 'Suite 818',
      'city': 'Port Mablefurt',
      'state': 'Arkansas',
      'country': 'Netherlands Antilles',
      'zipcode': '89975-6584',
      'geo': {
        'lat': '-42.9187',
        'lng': '8.5866'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    'uuid': '6a03248b-1752-4332-a3a9-7108528cc9d3',
    'name': 'Celestine',
    'jobTitle': 'Marketing',
    'email': 'Celestine.Casper59@hotmail.com',
    'username': 'Celestine.Casper',
    'phone': '1-830-046-3289',
    'avatar': '/static/avatar/a4.jpg',
    'status': 'false',
    'address': {
      'street': '9528 Schroeder Track',
      'suite': 'Apt. 443',
      'city': 'Godfreyburgh',
      'state': 'Montana',
      'country': 'Slovenia',
      'zipcode': '10220',
      'geo': {
        'lat': '36.8638',
        'lng': '20.0047'
      }
    }
  },
];
```

this is what i get right now :

[what i got](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-b99xBk89NII/XICvMy2SVTI/AAAAAAAABdg/IQ8P1HNhEqUPZUafOypDafaa74PwXffuACLcBGAs/s320/switch%2Bproblem%2B1.PNG)

[What i want to achieved](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CM7PDECPLS8/XICvM8aPyyI/AAAAAAAABdk/oWeCINgbrWsEA7Ck-ALeYeNWxRyuAQOpQCLcBGAs/s320/switch%2Bproblem%2B2.PNG)

I already try using:

```
<div slot="widget-content">
  <div class="basic">
    <v-switch value="true" :label="props.item.status ? 'Active': 'Non-Active'" v-model="props.item.status" color="success" @change="getStatus(props.item.status)"></v-switch>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to click it 2 times It always return `null` instead of `false`

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data has status as a string not a boolean.  Give that a go.

Comment: you're right, in first i think it the same but when i try it seems i forget to remove this `''`, thank you very much ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answer, you can set a default true and false value to a v-switch like that :

```
<v-switch
  false-value="I'm false"
  true-value="I'm true"
></v-switch>
```